# how to hide contents of a element but not the element itself

Tags: javascript

I want to hide the contents of td(including text and html) but not the td itself, I dont want to remove, because I need to display some a tag elements afterwards. I can't create any class or id or remove anything. its already prewritten code I need to use only javascript.

```
<td>
   prev
   <a class="simpleclass" href="example.com">
   2
   <a class="simpleclass" href="example1.com">
   1
   <a class="simpleclass" href="example2.com">
   Next
 </td>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: why downvote? please tell me why

Answer (score -1):

use `.children().hide()` on your selector - if it's the only td on the page you could use

`$('td').children().hide()`

if it's a more complicated page you'll need to build a selector for that td, but once you have it you can use .children().hide() to hide everything within it but leave it on the page

Comment: thanks for your answer children().hide() hides only html elements not text

Comment: $('td').each(function(){$(this).hide()}) - that should work - finds everything within the td and hides it

Comment: post a fiddle or codepen then with your code, this worked for me locally